# Visual Studio 2013 Community Bit Bucket dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Part of our team does java development and we all use BitBucket for source control.  One of their data models is checked into BitBucket and i'd like to be able to to automatically add the latest and greatest files to my VIsual Studio project.  I already figured out how to add BitBucket repositories to VS but I can't seem to get that repo to my C# project.

Anyway is this even possible?  I am thinking a maven like plug-in.

I followed this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/900204/Getting-started-with-GIT-Visual-Studio-and-BitBuck

Comment: A maven like plug-in would be NuGet, but someone would have to package this up and create it.  It sounds like you'd like it to be repackaged on build so that the latest and greatest is always in the NuGet package.  That's more involved than a simple answer can do.  If you just want the binaries one time, though, you can `git clone https://whatever@bitbucket`, load that solution in visual studio and build it, then take the binaries from the `bin` folder and add them as references to your project

Comment: Thanks!  I'll research NuGet.